# How do create a list of markers using data from a database

Tags: c#, linq, blazor, radzen

I am using radzen to generate code in blazor to create a web front-end.

Radzen has the option to add a googlemap component, which has markers to pinpoint a specific location  on the map. The API for this is at the bottom.

One of the parameters of the markers are "googlemappositions", this takes 2 doubles as parameters(latitude and longitude).

I would like to add all of these latitude and longitude values from the database to the map.

Using LINQ I created some queries to retrieve the longitude and latitude values.

I attempted to loop over the data from the database to then add them to an array of "googlemappositions"  but it doesn't seem to work. I am not sure where the problem is.

What I want psuedocode:

```
Googlemappositions = 
[
Googlemapposition1() { latitude1 , longitude1 }
,
Googlemapposition2() { latitude2 , longitude2 }
,
Googlemapposition3() { latitude3 , longitude3 }
,
Googlemapposition4() { latitude4 , longitude4 }
]

 for each (item in googlemappositions)
{ markername = bridgename  position = item}
```

I assume I made mistakes at the queries or the loop.
I tried to debug the code but I am not receiving any relevant information regarding the map.

//Database

Table:Bridge

Columns:

ID[1,2,3,4,5]

Name[east, bigbridge,small,westbridge,north]

Latitudes[54.2333 , 53.2929, 56.39449, 53.20933,52.1]

Longitudes[4.3224,3.9953,4.232323,3.23503,5.6789]

//Code

//Create getDbdata

```cs
    [Table("bridges", Schema = "public")]
    public partial class Bridge
    {
        public double latitude
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double longitude
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

//Retrieve Latitude Query

```
      public List<double> GetLatitude(Bridges bridge)
        {

            List<double> latitudes = Context.Bridges
                               .Where(i => i.id == bridge.id)
                               .Select(i => i.latitude)
                               .ToList();
            return latitudes;
        }
```

//Retrieve Longitude Query

```
        public List<double> GetLongitude(Bridges bridge)
        {

            List<double> longitudes = Context.Bridges
                                .Where(i => i.id == bridge.id)
                               .Select(i => i.longitude)
                               .ToList();
            return longitudes;
        }
```

//Create positions

```
public List<GoogleMapPosition> GetPosition()
        {
            List<GoogleMapPosition> positions = new List<GoogleMapPosition>();
            GoogleMapPosition[] posArray = new GoogleMapPosition[] { };

            for (int i = 0; i < posArray.Length; i++)
            {
                GoogleMapPosition item = posArray[i];
                foreach (var b in getBridgeResults)
                {
                    foreach (var (latitude, longitude) in GetLatitude(b).SelectMany(latitude => GetLongitude(b).Select(longitude => (latitude, longitude))))
                    {
                        positions.Add(new GoogleMapPosition() { Lat = latitude, Lng = longitude });
                    }
                }                
            }
            return positions;
        }
```

//Add Positions to Map

```
<Markers>
        @foreach (var item in GetPosition())
        { 
                    <RadzenGoogleMapMarker Label="bridge.name" Position=@item Title="bridge.name">
                    </RadzenGoogleMapMarker>
        }
      </Markers>
```

"RadzenGoogleMap" ApI:
https://www.radzen.com/documentation/blazor/googlemap/

Comment: Break your problem down. There are at least 2-3 individual pieces here.

Comment: Specifically, using C#(Blazor) I would like to have multiple markers on a map. The data from the markers(latitude, longitude) I would like to retrieve from my database and loop over them. After this I would like to convert these values into markers that I can then use on the googlemap.

Comment: I  will add code shortly

Comment: So is your problem 1) with reading from your database, 2) with transforming the data you read into an appropriate format, or 3) with creating the markers on radzengooglemap (whatever that is)? This is what I mean when I say you need to break your problem down; it should not be "all of the above" because some parts are problems you can solve yourself without outside influence, right?

Comment: In that case the problem is creating the markers

Comment: I will try to pin point the issue for a more clear question

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?  Is al you r code getting executed. Step through code and make sure you get to all the function and make sure the parameter list is correct.  Are you "data-bind the Markers Properties"?

Comment: I tried some of your Marker coordinates, the first two are in the middle of the sea, is it intended?

Comment: The coordinates are just examples to try to get many coordinates to work

Comment: I believe the problem might be in the loop I am not sure if what I did was entirely possible. But I have not received any error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it will be right, if you set "<RadzenGoogleMapMarker Label="bridge.name" Position="@item"    " with double quotes, instead of "
"